# Clangd in VSCode: .clang-format and .clang-tidy files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, clang-format

I've been trying to setup my VSCode to work with Clangd as a LSP server for my Cpp projects. I've successfully established basic functions such as the LSP itself and configured correct build settings in order to generate index database.

However I was not able to get my .clang-format and .clang-tidy configurations to work. It seems, that clangd does not search for those files.

I suspect, that this might be linked to the fact, that VSCode uses the clangd in stdin/stdout mode, however, I am not sure.

Thanks and have a nice day :)

(I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Clang+LLCM 9.0.0)

Comment: For clang-format, did you set `"editor.defaultFormatter": "llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd",` in your workspace settings?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and finally, I found out that it was because the encoding of the *.clangformat* file was *UTF-16*, I changed it to *UTF-8* encoding and it solved the problem.